# How to remove bullet points from <li> in TCPDF

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

This is part of a PDF that I generated with TCPDF:

[image]

How would I remove the bullet points?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
li { list-style-type: none; }
```

That should make the markers disappear from the list.

Comment: If these li are encapsulated within <ul></ul> tags, you may need to place that "ul" before the "li" in the code. Try the original answer first.

Comment: Good to hear! :) would you mind accepting the answer so others can see the question is resolved? Thanks!

Comment: yes sure..done :) :)